# calculate with values from two different dicts and return keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to calculate the cosine similarity between all values of dict1 and all values of dict2.
when i'm done, i want to return the keys of the dicts where the similarity is high. To do that, I want to save the results of cosine similarity in a similarity dict.
This is my attempt:

```
similarity_dictionary = {}
for x in dict1:
    for y in dict2:
        for x_key, x_val in dict1.items():
            for y_key, y_val in dict2.items():
                cos_sim =  numpy.dot(x_val, y_val)/(norm(x_val,)*norm(y_val))
                dict_of_sims[[x_key, y_key]] = cos_sim
```

this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,300) and (1,300) not aligned: 300 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Could someone please help with 1. explain the error and 2. lead me in the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to calculate a dot product of two `1x300` matrices. The error simply states that this cannot work, since you can only multiply an `m x n` matrix with an `n x p` matrix (i.e. the 'inner dimensions' need to be the same).

Also, it is hard to say how to improve your code if you don't provide a minimal working example.

Comment: thank you @Corinna Bürger, so i need to transform the marices in order to get the same n?

Comment: Exactly. I would recommend you check the calculation results for consistency afterwards. If that goes well, you should be all set. Numpy has matrix transposition functions you can use.